# Trouble getting windowmanager properties to save it's contents with blend file

Tags: python

I'd like the contents of this custom editor panel to persist with the file.

I can't seem to get my `PropertyGroup` or even a `StringProperty` to save with the blend file.

```
class PG_mypg(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    custString = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="custString")

bpy.utils.register_class(PG_mypg)

# this adds it but it doesn't persist in the file
bpy.types.WindowManager.myPanelSettings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=PG_mypg)

# even this one doesn't save either
bpy.types.WindowManager.myCustString = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="customString")
```

Note that I want this to be set for my window, not per object.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an empty object type that isn't visible in the 3d view? This is how I would do it in unity3d.

Answer (score 6):

Custom properties to the `bpy.types.WindowManager` type don't serialize to .blend
<strike>(as if `options={'SKIP_SAVE'}` was set)</strike>.

Your options are to use

- `bpy.types.Scene`, but you will need to chose one scene instance to store the actual properties, and if that scene is deleted, they will be gone
- Serialization: serialize your data to a string and make it the text body of a new text datablock. Give the datablock a name that starts with a dot, e.g. `.my-data`, to hide it in the interface. It is less likely to be removed like a scene this way.
- [AddonPreferences](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html) or saving to a custom configuration file - if the data is relevant to not just the current .blend, but the local Blender installation

Comment: The comment about 'SKIP_SAVE' isnt really correct, `SKIP_SAVE` is for operators not to reuse previous settings.

Comment: I like the suggestion for AddonPreferences but it doesn't solve this problem in particular.

Comment: @ideasman42: Interesting, this isn't documented anywhere it seems. BenL: That's right, it really depends on the use case.

Comment: I'm just going to add a utility to copy or reference the data block from one scene to another. That is the hack that seems the least hacky.