# Sharing data between Operators

Tags: python, operator

I have two sets of Operators. The first set, lets call it A, produce data. The second set, lets call it B, needs to read this data.
What possibilities do I have to store my data from set A, so it is accessable for the ones from B?

Additional info:

- The type of the data is a dictionary
- It is not neccessary to store it in the blender file to make it persistend for later use
- When Operators from A are called multiple times, the data shall be overwritten, so the Operarators from B always gets the latest data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way is to use a global variable, although I don't recommend to make use of the `global` keyword on a dict directly. I suggest to use a class instead:

```
class G:
    pass

class OperatorA(...): ...
    G.your_dict = {"foo": "bar"}

class OperatorB(...): ...
    print(G.your_dict)
```

You may replace `pass` with class variable declarations if B might try to access it before A sets it:

```
class G:
    your_dict = {"default": None}
```

If the data is really related to let's say `OperatorA`, you may also use that class instead of `G`. Inside of a method in `OperatorA`, you can either refer to the class via the explicit name, or via `self.__class__`.

Comment: Where should I instantiate the class G?

Comment: Nowhere, you use the class itself, not any instance of it. Declare it in the global scope. It will be like a singleton. Classes are first-class citizens, just like functions - you can reference them like any other object (int, float, dict, function, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Another place you might store a dictionary is in the scene itself.

```
bpy.context.scene['mydataparams'] = {'value':1}
bpy.context.scene['mydataparams']['value']
```

It will get stored with the blender file. Whether that's a good thing or a bad thing is up to you.

Comment: It shouldn't be serialized if you use `bpy.context.window_manager`, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/trouble-getting-windowmanager-properties-to-save-its-contents-with-blend-file