# store custom data to blender file (json text)

Tags: add-on, customization, data-blocks, packed-data

I am trying to write/read custom data in blender files (a json text in this case). For that I want to use my custom addon. But there are some requirements about how this data is stored:

1. Ideally this data would be available independently of the scene or the objects present in the .blend file. Also `bpy.types.Scene` or at `object` level would not be good enough.
2. This data in the .blend file would persist if open and resaved using a blender editor that doesnt have our custom addon installed.

All I found about this is this rather old answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8443
Using a hidden text file is not perfect but would work. I am just wondering there may be a more canonical way I could not find, besides I didnt try that yet and in case it still works, it may not be recommended in the future (using blender 2.93)?

Comment: If you want the custom data in the blend file, then writing a json file into a text block is the only viable approach still.